# Configure Tomcat 5.5 as a Solaris 10 service

Tags: tomcat, solaris

I need to configure the Apache Tomcat 5.5 as a Solaris 10 service or as an alternative - any other way to run it on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun has 'evolved past' SysVinit to something called the 'Services Management Framework' (or SMF for short).  There's an article on it [here](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/selfheal/smf-quickstart.jsp) and a more dev-oriented article [here](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/selfheal/sdev_intro.jsp) that includes instruction on how to create your own service, which is, I think, what you want.

Answer (score 1):

SMF, the Service Management Facility, uses XML files, so called 'manifests' to store information about services to start. Take an existing service, say ssh, and export its manifest to a file.

```
$ svccfg export ssh > ssh-manifest.xml
```

Analyze this file, take out what you don't need, update the service name and import it:

```
$ svccfg import < your-manifest.xml
```

Then set the service to run by default:

```
$ svcadm enable your-service
```

Speaking of Tomcat, you can get prepackaged Tomcat from OpenCSW. They have three versions of Tomcat packaged:

```
maciej@netra ~ $ pkg-get -a | grep tomcat
             tomcat4 4.1.37,REV=2008.11.30
             tomcat5 5.5.27,REV=2008.11.29
             tomcat6 6.0.18,REV=2008.11.29
```

Packages from OpenCSW configure SMF - they import the manifest and enable the service upon installation.